# Testing controllers = integration test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, controller, integration-testing

once I asked a similar question before. We have a forum system:

```
class ForumThread
{
    public function delete ($threadId)
    {
        Container::getPost()->deletePostsByThreadId ($threadId);
        Container::getSql()->sql ('DELETE FROM threads WHERE ID = '.$threadId);
    }
}

class Post
{
    public function deletePostsByThreadId ($threadId)
    {
        Container::getSql()->sql ('DELETE FROM posts WHERE THREAD_ID = '.$threadId);
    }
}
```

as you can see, it gets the post and thread objects from a container, it can be replaced, mocked, etc. When unit-testing, I felt something missing: so, its ok to test if a forum thread is actually deleted - so post too. This is what unittesting for - but do they work **together** well? If they works OK standalone, its not guaranted that they work together well. If two lego elements are well made, they might not fit to each other.
Here enter the integration test:

```
class Controller
{
    function controllerDelete()
    {
        Container::getForumThread()->delete ($_POST['ID']);
    }
}
```

I guess here I could check both SQL tables. Is my theory OK? Because if controller testing was unittest-like, it wouldnt really make sense, since controllers are typically the shortest classes (once I made a test ForumThread::delete, the test controller::controllerDelete would be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already know [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) is mostly concentrated on smallest testable part of an application. So if they pass – your unit level is OK. [Integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) is yet another thing – modules combined and tested as a group. So as bottom line to:

> Is my theory OK?

Yes. What you need to cover in *controller testing* on this level is functional, performance, and reliability you’ve already placed as per application design and requirements.